# python csv remove rows error ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, csv

I want to remove rows from a CSV dictionary. My current approach is to put all the data from the CSV into a temporary list from which I `.remove()` the unwanted row and then rewrite the entire CSV without the unwanted row.

The code I have so far is:

```
def delete():
    while (True):
        request = str(input("Delete by: fname | lname | cnumber: "))

        with open("customers.csv", "r") as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            
            if (request == "fname"):
                fname = str(input("Enter first name: "))
                for line in reader:
                    if (line["First name"] == fname):
                        selectedLine = line
                break
            
    listLines.remove(selectedLine)
```

Would appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Comment: Where is `listLines` initialized?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes. I initialized them outside the function as a global variable

Comment: As the error says, `listLines` does not contain `selectedLine`.  Without seeing the actual content of both of those variables, there's not much more we can do to help.

Comment: It looks like `selectedLine` is a dictionary.  What are the items in `listLines`?  Are they also dictionaries, or are they just lines of text?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JohnGordon Okay... I messed up. Hadn't initalized `listLines` as you had pointed out. Got lost in the big chunk of code. But it works fine now. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the `csv` file contains the following data:

```
Michal, Brave, 55
Mary, Jane, 21
John, Smith, 34
```

With this code we can accomplish what you need:

```
# read the file and separate name, surname and age
with open('customers.csv', 'r') as file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        person_data = line.split(',')
        name = person_data[0].title()
        surname = person_data[1].title()
        age = person_data[2]

        print(f'{name}{surname} is {age}.')

    # recreate the list of rows where the name provided by the user is not included
    prompt_user = input("Enter name for deletion: ")
    lines = [line + '\n' for line in lines if prompt_user not in line]
    
    # write the changes to the file
    with open('customers.csv', 'w') as file_write:
        file_write.writelines(lines)
```